# Using a non-saved image in a Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using a Canvas (and Python 2.7) to display an image which is storen in a bytearray (in PGM format).

For the moment, I save it to disk, then contruct a PhotoImage from the file.

How can I avoid saving the file ? I tried to use cStringIO to make a 'string-file', then passing it to the PhotoImage using encode64, the problem is that cStringIO.write doesn't accept bytearray : I've got an error :

```
TypeError: must be string or pinned buffer, not bytearray
```

I'd like to avoid using external libraries, such as PIL, if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Fred

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the suggestion with `PhotoImage` is:

> The PhotoImage can also read base64-encoded GIF files from strings.
>   You can use this to embed images in Python source code (use functions
>   in the base64 module to convert binary data to base64-encoded strings)

You can convert the byte array to a string: `byteString = ''.join([ str(x) for x in bytes ])`
See if this works.

[Link to base64 module](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html)

Comment: I didn't notice that PhotoImage could only take GIF encoded strings. I thought it'd work with any format PhotoImage can read as a file.

I think I've no choice but to use PIL. Thanks for pointing my mistake.